# Writing pojo class for complex payload

Tags: java, pojo

```
  "profile": {
    "role": "xxxxxxxx",

    "groups": [
      "xxxxxxxxx"

    ],
    
  }
}
```

how to write pojo clas for array ,where here groups is array which can accpt any number of assigned groups , inside array it doesnot have any key value pair ,only will get integer as value

Comment: a) I can't see anything complex here. b) i have no idea what you actually want to do.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Arrays never need "key value pairs" (which in json, would be objects)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `role` is of `String` type and `groups` is of `int[]` (as you mentioned).

```
class profile {
    String role;
    int[] groups;
}
```